# Segregating roscolsole output (C++)

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running a node that has two main threads going on it it. I would like to segregate the output from these two threads by sending the text in ROS_INFO/ROS_ERROR/etc. to one of two different terminals. For example:

```
ROS_INFO("term1", "This should appear on Terminal 1");
ROS_INFO("term2", "This should appear on Terminal 2");
```

I want to do this because the two threads have quite different purposes, and I want to be able to easily see which output is from which thread and have it all together in one place. Is there any convenient way of doing this? I'm not overly familiar with Linux, but maybe piping the output to something other than stdout and then having a shell script that reads from the output and writes to stdout on a different terminal?

EDIT: is there a way to bump this question, or put a bounty on it or something? The two answers given do not, unfortunately, solve the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209522/segregating-roscolsole-output-(c++)/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-27**:
There's no way to put a bounty on questions on ROS Answers. I haven't heard of anyone trying to do anything like what you're proposing, so you're not likely to find a pre-made solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All `ROS_CONSOLE` macros have a version with postfix `_NAMED`, e. g.

```
ROS_INFO(  ... )
```

and

```
ROS_INFO_NAMED( name, ... )
```

(See your macros_generated.h; it should be in /opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h)

Calling `ROS_INFO_NAMED` with an name following the same args like a `ROS_INFO` call results in the same behaviour but the node name is overriden by the name you have given to it.

So you can easily always call `ROS_INFO_NAMED`, `ROS_WARN_NAMED`, `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED` and so on with different names in both threads of your node and then open two instances of rqt_console and filter in both instances the messages by name....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-05-20**:
This sounds pretty much like what I need. Can you elaborate a little bit on the rqt_console bit? It looks like rqt_console is a GUI, but I need the output in a terminal because it's running over a simple SSH connection.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-05-21**:
the logs are published to `/rosout` so how can also run rqt_console on a remote conputer (if it is in your ROS network)

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-05-21**:
Yeah, so I was looking at /rosout to try to find a way to just subscribe to the logs and print them in a different node. Unfortunately, the rosgraph_msgs/Log message that is published on /rosout only includes the name of the node, not the name of the logger that I provided in ROS_INFO_NAMED().

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-05-21**:
So, since I can't get the logger name out of the /rosout message, I can't separate which ones were from ROS_INFO_NAMED("term1",...) and which ones were from ROS_INFO_NAMED("term2"...) if they originated from the same node.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-22**:
To view them separately use a tool like rqt_console and the filters to get the separate streams after creating the named loggers.

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-05-22**:
@tfoote yes I can do it with rqt_console, but as mentioned in a previous comment I need it to be terminal-based (non-gui) because I need to run it over an SSH tunnel.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-27**:
ROS is network-based; you should be able to set the ROS_MASTER_URI on your local machine to use the ROS master on your robot, and run rqt_console locally.